# jupyter is not responding in dataproc images cluster

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-dataproc

I have created custom image but when I try to run jupyterlab it doesn't show any result for anything, I have created he cluster adding optional components to it

```
--optional-components=ANACONDA,JUPYTER 
--enable-component-gateway
```

and the jupyter packages which is in the req text which I used to build my custom image is:

```
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client
jupyter-console==5.2.0
jupyter-core==4.6.3
jupyterhub==1.0.0
jupyterlab==0.32.1
jupyterlab-launcher==0.10.5
jupyterlab-pygments==0.1.2
```

and the base image version I am using is :Image Version: 1-4-41-debian10

any idea why it might not be responding? it doesn't show any error just loading without any result

[image]

Comment: Why do you install your own Jupyter packages? The default doesn't work?